# Capturing AccountTeamMembers on Account Object

Tags: account, account-teams

I want to populate AccountTeamMember names related to particular account on account object field.
As Trigger is not allowed on AccountTeam or AccountTeamMember i think of writing a batch class to update the account field but problem is:

1) Suppose a accountteammember is added and during batch class run its name gets updated on account object field, now after some time it gets deleted. now on deletion i want to remove accountteammember name from account object field in which earlier i captured the value but in soql query id didnt get the deleted accountteammember inspite of using ALL ROWS keyword.

What is the best method to handle situation like i can have the names of all accountteammemebers on account level which are associated to that account.

Comment: I've known a number of companies recreate the object using their own custom object...

Comment: @Girbot What else is the solution?

Comment: As it's a custom object triggers are available, so you can add your logic there.

Answer (score 2):

One way of handling this if doing it via a batch class using a query is to run your query to determine who *should be* there and also query to discover who *currently is* there. Compare the results of the two queries by account (run them as a single query if you wish, I'm just distinguishing between the two results here). If someone is not on the list of who *should* be there, they get deleted from the list of who *is* there.

Batch class methods would seem pretty straightforward for what you describe. You can even chain another "clean-up" batch class that runs afterward to check for any records that were modified while the initial class was running. Dan Appleman discusses some of these patterns in book Advanced Apex Programming Ver 3.